# Get the HTML table Checked item Id's to list and Pass to Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET MVC project, there is a table that shows the user view the information of `file type` and `Id` (Hidden).

Whenever the user put checked the checkboxes and clicks on the `Send Request Mail` Button, I want to get the IDs of the checked rows and pass them to the controller as a List of Ids.

This is the table view

```
<tbody> 
@foreach (var item in Model.ReqDocumentsViewModel.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)) 
{  <tr class="even pointer">
    <td style="display:none;">@item.Id</td>
    <td>@item.FileType</td>
    <td>@item.Note</td> @if (item.RequestStatus == false) { <td> Not Requested; </td> } else { <td> Requested; </td> } <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="@item.Id" id="chk" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" onclick="RemoveReqDocument()" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
    </td>
  </tr> 
  } 
 </tbody>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary sm" onclick="SendMailNotification();">Send Request Mail</button>
```

This is what I tried.

```
function SendMailNotification() {

  const selectedRows = [...$('table tbody tr:has("input:checked")')]
    .map(tr => [...$(tr).find('td:lt(1)')]
      .reduce((res, td) => (res[$(td).attr('prop')] = $(td).text(), res), {}))

  console.log(selectedRows)

  var newOrders = $.map(selectedRows, function (element) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var key in element) {
      obj.Id = key;

    }
    return obj;

  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Task/RequestDocument",
    data: JSON.stringify(newOrders),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (r) {
      if (r == false) {
        alert("You have to enter Order Qty first");
      } else {
        alert("Order Created");
        location.reload();
      }

    }
  });
}
```

In Controller

```
public JsonResult RequestDocument(List < ReqDocList > idQs) 
{

}
```

Model

```
public class ReqDocList
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
       
 }
```

Comment: Move the id to a semantic position, eg `<tr data-id='@item.id'>` then reverse your selector and map directly `$("table.mytable input:checked").parent("tr").map((i, e) => $(e).data("id")).toArray()`  - it's unclear (to me) what the .reduce is for/does as there doesn't seem to be a "prop" attribute, but maybe I'm reading it incorrectly.

Comment: Also if you have jQuery, why not use it as far as it gets you? `const selectedIds = $('table tbody tr:has("input:checked")').map(function() { return $(this).first().text() }).get()`

Comment: @freedomn-m I got this code from the internet. Can u suggest a better one ?

Comment: I believe I just did, as did @mplungjan with another alternative.

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm not good with javascript yet. Still learning. I have used ``const selectedIds = $('table tbody tr:has("input:checked")').map(function() { return $(this).first().text() }).get()`` this for my example. But I don't know how to take the exact ``id`` from the output and pass to the controller.

Comment: Ok, looks like your question could do with some clarification.  We've picked up on *I want to get the IDs of the checked rows* and *assumed* this part of your code isn't working.  Please clarify which parts do work (eg getting the list of IDs) and which part don't (eg posting to the controller).   As is, the question doesn't actually state what your problem is (or even contain a *question*)

Comment: @freedomn-m Here in the table there a columns ``Item,Id | Item.FileType | Item.Note | Item.RequestState | CheckBox and at the end of the table there's a button to confirm. So what I want is When User ``Checked`` some rows and clicks the button, I want to get the ``Item.Id`` list and pass to the controller as a list of Id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get the IDs of the checked rows and pass them to the
> controller as a List of Ids.

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

ReqDocListVM:

```
public class ReqDocListVM
    {     
        public ICollection<ReqDocList> ReqDocList { get; set; }
    }
```

TaskController:

```
public class TaskController : Controller
    {
        public static List<ReqDocList> ReqDocList = new List<ReqDocList>()
        {
            new ReqDocList() {Id =1},
            new ReqDocList() {Id =2},
            new ReqDocList() {Id =3},
            new ReqDocList() {Id =4}
        };
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var model =new  ReqDocListVM();
            model.ReqDocList= ReqDocList;   
            return View(model);

        }
        public JsonResult RequestDocument(List<int> ids)
        {
            return Json(ids);
        }

    }
```

Index view:

```
@model ReqDocListVM

<table class="table table-bordered table-light">
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ReqDocList)
    {
            <tr class="even-pointer" chk-id="@item.Id">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="@item.Id" id="chk" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" onclick="RemoveReqDocument()" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
<button id="bt"type="button" class="btn btn-primary sm" >Send Request Mail</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var Ids = [];       
        $(".even-pointer").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
            var Id = $(this).attr('chk-id');
            if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
                Ids.push(Id);
            }
            else {
               Ids = Ids.filter(function (id) {
                    return id !== Id;
                });
            }                
            });

        $("#bt").click(function () {           
            console.log(Ids);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Task/RequestDocument",
                data: { "ids": Ids },                
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, well explained step by step, and my issue is now solved. Thanks again for your effort. :)